# What is point of implementing the Comparable interface in my classes?

Tags: java, comparable

I don't get the point of implementing the `Comparable` interface, since I can't use the comparison operators `<`, `<=`, `>=`, and `>` for my custom classes like I would be able to with operator overriding in languages like C++; I still have to call the `compareTo` method directly.

I could write my own boolean methods like `isEqual` or `bigger`, which would be just as useful, if not more so, than the `compareTo` method.

Am I missing something? What is the point of implementing it?

Comment: I didn't downvote myself but unclear questions get downvoted quite often. Though I feel if you do so, you should explain why / what should be improved.

Comment: Hello, even though i am always welcome to constructive criticism, i dont understand how this question could be more clear. You dont have many ways to explain sth you dont understand. Even saying not understanding point of sth in one sentence is enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Comparable` interface provides a means of communication to the implemented sorting algorithms, which would be impossible using custom methods for comparison.

Comment: So you can do `Collections.sort(....)` <- a collection of your Object and stuff like that

Comment: Or more specifically, the interface lets the runtime know that it can be sorted, and how to do so. A sorting algorithm doesn't know about your isBiggerThan() method, but it does know about the Comparable interface

Answer (score 4):

The point of implementing `Comparable` is being able to sort arrays, Collections, etc... based on different criteria.

Answer (score 3):

Other classes can take a parameter of type Comparable. They will not know your special methods, but they know the interface and can use it if implemented.

As an example, the method Collections.sort() can make use of an Comparable: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)